# Why does querying xrandr briefly freeze the screen?

Tags: debian, video, xrandr, freeze

Every time I run `xrandr --query` my screen freezes very briefly. It's enough to be jarring if I'm watching an animation or a video -- which sucks, because I have a script querying xrandr every 3 seconds to check if it should reconfigure the monitors.

To demonstrate, here's a fairly smooth GIF (the spinning dancer illusion): https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Left_spinning_dancer.gif

Run `xrandr --query` while the image is displayed and you should see it hiccup briefly just as you run the command. Running a different command does not produce this effect.

I'm running Debian Wheezy (7.8) and `uname -a` produces `Linux bc-timmc 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I suppose I'm both asking "why" and "how can I avoid this".

Answer (score 0):

As to the second part of your question (not in the header)

Use xdpyinfo instead, if you want to read something like screen resolution. It doesn't cause that brief freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was able to solve this problem by downgrading from [DRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure)3 to DRI2. For my hardware, this did the trick:

```
tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf<<EOF
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "DRI" "2"             # DRI3 is now default 
EndSection
EOF
```